# Google search operator "site:" ... how to limit its scope?

Tags: google-search

Assume there is a website with the domain name `baz.tld`. It has content. There is also content on subdomains `foo.baz.tld` and `bar.baz.tld`, but there is no `www.baz.tld` subdomain.

The most frequent search operator I use on Google is `site:` to limit the scope to a particular domain. This works fine when specifying a particular subdomain such as `site:foo.baz.tld` (which limits search result to that subdomain). But when I give `site:baz.tld` I end up getting results for `foo.baz.tld` and `bar.baz.tld` but the ones for `baz.tld` end up somewhere towards the end (several pages forward) of the search results.

How can I achieve something like `site:foo.baz.tld` but limit it to only `baz.tld`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the closest you can come is to restrict your search to the domain you want, then subtract out the subdomains you don't.  For example, compare the results of these two queries:

> [visual studio
>   site:microsoft.com](http://www.google.com/search?ie=ISO-8859-1&hl=en&source=hp&q=visual+studio+site%3amicrosoft.com&gbv=1&oq=visual+studio+site%3amicrosoft.com)
>
> [visual studio site:microsoft.com
>   -site:msdn.microsoft.com](http://www.google.com/search?ie=ISO-8859-1&hl=en&source=hp&q=visual%20studio%20site%3amicrosoft.com%20-site%3amsdn.microsoft.com&gbv=1&oq=visual%20studio%20site%3amicrosoft.com%20-site%3amsdn.microsoft.com)

Google doesn't support wildcarding in `site:` keyword as in `-site:*.microsoft.com`, so you'll have to subtract each subdomain you'd like excluded one-at-a-time.